# QGridLayout и QMenuBar

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

У меня класс наследуется от QWidget. В этом классе я создал grid_layout и меню классы. Создал пункт меню и отобразил его. А grid_layout присвоил так.

```
this->setLayout ( grid_layout );
```

То что есть в grid layout перекрывает меню. Как сделать чтобы отображалось нормально?

Answer (score 0):

Надо к gridlayout присвоит меню бар функции.

```
mlayout->setMenuBar(menubar);
```